# Calculating a GPA in R

Tags: r

I need to calculate GPAs in a really large dataset. I have row level data of each student's grade for each subject they've taken and the number of credit points the unit was worth. I can do it manually in excel but the dataset is too large. Hoping I can do this in R

Students can achieve a score of 0 to 7 for each subject they undertake and a subject can be 12.5 or 25 credit points. The credit points work like a weight - so a 7 in a subject worth 25 credit points improves GPA more than a 7 in a subject worth 12.5 credit points. The GPA is calculated by multiplying the score by the credit points (e.g. 6 x 12.5) and then dividing that by the sum of credit points to get a score between 0 and 7.

So for example if in one semester a student takes four subjects and achieves the following results

`Subject 1 - score = 6, credit points = 12.5 Subject 2 - score = 7, credit points = 12.5 Subject 3 - score = 6, credit points = 12.5 Subject 4 - score = 5, credit points = 25`

Their GPA would be 5.8. The sum behind it is (6*12.5 + 7*12.5 + 6*12.5 + 5*25) / (12.5 + 12.5 + 12.5 + 25).

What I can't figure out how to do in R is how to calculate this in bulk. Because each unit has a different amount of credit points (weight) I need to calculate the score * credit points first and then add that up separately for each students and not multiply the sum of all scores with the sum of all credits.

Any ideas where to start? Or functions I can look into?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you need more help than user2974951's answer  provides, you'll probably have to tell us more about how your data is formatted. If you already know the formula you need to use, and if you have all the required data in R, it should be a simple matter to apply your formula to your data. If you have a separate table that contains each subject and the number of credit points it's worth, you can join that to your student results table. You'll then have one table, with each row containing each of the variables you need for your formula.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data in such a format:

```
df=structure(list(student = c(1, 1, 1, 1), subject = c(1, 2, 3, 
4), score = c(6, 7, 6, 5), points = c(12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 25)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

  student subject score points
1       1       1     6   12.5
2       1       2     7   12.5
3       1       3     6   12.5
4       1       4     5   25.0
```

then

```
aggregate(
  (score*points)/sum(points)~student,
  data=df,
  FUN=sum
)

  student (score * points)/sum(points)
1       1                          5.8
```